# Access Denied while putting file from HDFS to S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, oozie-workflow

I have written a Java program which is included in the oozie workflow which puts files from HDFS to S3 bucket. However, I am getting the following error

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied
>   (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
>   Request ID: 310F08CD4FF8B5D9), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   fAysD1vgtriV8x+sf1zqHk58eAT89Y6HD+ziEokaPvFPKwaPrHDxt5yygsiA1ktNVsyj+GTmbQ0=

I am creating the key path in S3 bucket dynamically in oozie workflow. 
For eg: If my file name is `abc_20171009.tsv.gz` then this file should be uploaded to bucket in the following path

```
tsvFile/year=2017/month=10/day=09/abc_20171009.tsv.gz
```

In the similar way other day files should be uploaded based on the date.
 My query is whether the key path should preexist in the bucket before uploading the files or it can be created dynamically?

```
 // Request server-side encryption.           

          BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey);
          AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
          PutObjectRequest request  = new PutObjectRequest("bucket_name", "key_name","");

          ObjectMetadata objectMetadata  = new ObjectMetadata();
          objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);

          request.setMetadata(objectMetadata); 

          PutObjectResult response = s3Client.putObject(request);

          LOGGER.info("Server Side Encryption successful" +response.getSSEAlgorithm());
```

**Note:I am able to manually put the file and connect to S3 bucket through AWS CLI.**

Answer (score 0):

the amazon S3 serive have a list of safe characters which might be used for S3 object key

> Safe Characters The following character sets are generally safe for
>   use in key names: • Alphanumeric characters [0-9a-zA-Z] • Special
>   characters !, -, _, ., *, ', (, and )

however what I can see, you are using `=`, which on the other hand is a special character requiring handling

> Characters That Might Require Special Handling The following
>   characters in a key name may require additional code handling and will
>   likely need to be URL encoded or referenced as HEX. Some of these are
>   non-printable characters and your browser may not handle them, which
>   will also require special handling

and one of those characters is `=`

perhaps, when you upload file manually, the `=` is automatically encoded. So you have to options, remove thos `=` signs or encode them (I would go with the first options)

Comment: Can you also confirm if the key path(tsvFile/year=2017/month=10/day=09/) needs to pre-exist before uploading the file or it can be created dynamically?

Comment: when you are uploading a file to S3, you are not creating any directories, what you are seeing over the web interface is simply an interpretation of the  object keys (so file a/b/c.txt is just one file on the S3, but on the web interface it is interpreted as nested directories). Coming back to your question as for each file in your "directory" tsvFile/year=2017/month=10/day=09/ will need to have escaped "=" signs, as there is no "pre-exist" directory

Comment: This is the issue I am facing currently - Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: x-amz-server-side-encryption header is not supported for this operation. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: A4563A21BFA23BCE), S3 Extended Request ID: HoAo1ia5jOO3zuNsBzOspmB5b+ZG9YQHgCuFvJnrd0iGEGegCpUoqMf7VWybOj0Np0KVjk5ovm8=